# Not sure why loop does not break

Tags: python, python-3.x, while-loop, break

So I'm missing something here. When a user has spent all of the points they have and are prompted on whether or not they would like to add more points to the pool, and the user selects 'n' they are continuously prompted to add more points to the pool. Which should not happen. I've tried fiddling around with the placement of the break, to no avail. When a user inputs 'n' the whole loop should cease. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

```
# Char Creator- pool of 30 pts, spend on Str, Health, Wisdom, Dex
# Spend points in pool on attr, take points and put them back into pool

pool = 30

attr = {'Strength' : 0, 'Health' : 0, 'Wisdom' : 0, 'Dexterity' : 0}

while True:
    while pool > 0:
        print('\t\t Time to spend some points! You have', pool, 'to spend')
        spend = input('Where would you like to spend your points?')
        if spend in attr:
            amount = int(input('How many points would you like to spend?'))
            if amount > pool:
                print('You do not have that many points! You have', pool, 'points!')
            else:
                attr[spend] += amount
                pool -= amount
                print(attr)
        else:
            print('Not a valid input. Please correct.')

    print('\t\t You have no more points! Add some to the pool!')

    while pool == 0:
        confirm = input('Would you like to add points back into the pool?')
        if confirm == 'y':
           take =  input('Where would you like to take points from?')
           if take in attr:
                number = int(input('How many points would you like to take?'))
                if attr[take] >= number:
                    pool += number
                    attr[take] -= number
                    print ('There are now', pool, 'points remaining') 
                elif attr[take] < number:
                    print('You dont have enough points to do that! You have', attr[take], 'points in', take)
           else:
               print('Please make a valid selection.')
        elif confirm == 'n':
            print('Goodbye!')

    break
```

Comment: looks like some of your `while` loops should be `if` statements or omitted

Comment: @cmd: They're `while` loops because of the `print('Not a valid input. Please correct.')` or `print('Please make a valid selection.')` paths

Answer (score 3):

Your `break` is not indented to be in the `elif` statement (or in the inner while loop):

```
        elif confirm == 'n':
            print('Goodbye!')

    break
```

Add two more tabs in front of `break`.

So that your program can end after breaking out of the inner loop, you'll also probably want to change

```
while True:
```

to

```
while points > 0:
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply- evidently its thought to be a silly question. Im just a beginner. I've tried this myself and the user is still prompted to add more points to the pool for some reason.

Comment: @Zack: That's because your `break` statement only breaks out of the inner while loop, not the outer one. Change the line `while True:` to `while points > 0` and you'll fix that. You'll also have to add a `break` line after `print ('There are now', pool, 'points remaining') ` so that you get out of that loop.